# How to use nodes twice in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

In my XML, I have chapters with titles and I need to generate a table of contents out of it so that:

```
<chapter id="1"><title>Chapter 1</title><p>text</p></chapter>
<chapter id="2"><title>Chapter 2</title><p>text</p></chapter>
```

converts to

```
<!-- Table Of Contents -->
<div class="contents">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">Chapter 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Chapter 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- Actual Content -->
<div class="chapter" id="1"><p>text</p></div>
<div class="chapter" id="2"><p>text</p></div>
```

Unfortunately, when I try to use `xsl:for-each` to generate the table of contents, the actual chapters seem to disappear from the output. How do I tackle this?

Comment: Could you please show the XSLT you are currently using for this example? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <div>
      <div class="contents">
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter" mode="contents" />
        </ul>
      </div>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter" />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="chapter" mode="contents">
    <li>
      <a href="#{@id}">
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="chapter">
    <div class="chapter" id="{@id}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="chapter/title" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to this input:

```
<chapters>
  <chapter id="1">
    <title>Chapter 1</title>
    <p>text</p>
  </chapter>
  <chapter id="2">
    <title>Chapter 2</title>
    <p>text</p>
  </chapter>
</chapters>
```

will produce:

```
<div>
  <div class="contents">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#1">Chapter 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#2">Chapter 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="chapter" id="1">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="chapter" id="2">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you could show us your XSLT (I would think that with 2,410 reputation points providing that would be obvious to you), we can tell you what you're doing incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks, I was not yet comfortable using modes and didn't understand how to apply them in this situation.